# Virtuozzo, cannot connect to ssh server or do any operations in console PRL_ERR_VZCTL_OPERATION_FAILED

Tags: remote-access, remote-server, virtuozzo

I'm trying to connect to server from ssh but it stuck on connection process, console is unavailable too, when I'm trying to start or repair it throws error PRL_ERR_VZCTL_OPERATION_FAILED [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eu2E0.png), that may be problem with whole server or only with virtuozzo?

Trying to find solutions for PRL_ERR_VZCTL_OPERATION_FAILED but they require connection to server

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
modprobe ploop && \
modprobe pfmt_ploop1 && \
modprobe pfmt_raw && \
modprobe pio_direct
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. You should say what the commands you're suggesting do in addition to providing the flat commands. This helps users determine if your commands are relevant to their situation.